# SQLBulkCopy vs SQL bulk insert special characters

Tags: special-characters, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, codepages

I currently have a routine written in .Net which is using SQLBulkCopy. I'm re-writing this routine using conventional SQL, thus I'm using bulk insert.

I am having a problem when it comes to special characters. In particular there is the **ŷ** character which is converted to **?** when using SQLBulkCopy. However when I use bulk insert it is converted to the **²** character. I need to somehow end up with the ? character to stick to the original output.

If it makes any difference, the file I'm importing is a Unix ANSI encoded file

Any tips please?